# Ninject is not resolving via DependencyResolver in Application_Start

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, ninject

I was trying to solve this for entire morning but seems that its time to ask for advice.

I have an MVC / WebApi / SignalR application. I have a service which I would like to start together with web application. And I would like this service to be injected. So this is what I am trying to do:

```
public static class NinjectWebCommon 
{
   ...

   private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
    {
        GlobalHost.DependencyResolver = new Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Ninject.NinjectDependencyResolver(kernel); 

        kernel.Bind<PricingService>().ToSelf().InSingletonScope();
    }
}

public class Application : HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        ...
        PricingService pricingService = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<PricingService>();
    }
}
```

My problem is that the `pricingService` variable is null.

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7053532/accessing-ninject-kernel-in-application-start) this pattern should work but it does not. May be there is an influence from SignalR dependency resolver, but I am not really sure.

At the same time, when I'm using a constructor injection inside WebApi controller, injection works fine.

```
public class MyController : ApiController
{
    private readonly PricingService _pricingService;

    public MyController (PricingService pricingService)
    {
        _pricingService = pricingService;
    }
}
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Make sure that your DependencyResolver.Current in Application_Start is an instance of NinjectDependencyResolver.  If it is not, make sure that you've got your configuration in the right place/right time in the application start up process.

Comment: Steve, thanks for the prompt answer. DependencyResolver.Current is NOT an instance of NinjectDependencyResolver. As for initialization, I do not register Resolver myself. I am using a Ninject.MVC3 package and I was under impression that this would be done automatically (somewhere). I've checked that the method RegisterServices of NinjectWebCommon class is called before Application_Start. Do I need to do some extra initialization manually?

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to Steve's comment I was able to resolve the issue.

The part that was missing is registiring a NinjectDependencyResolver in MVC infrastructure:

```
private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
{
    DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new NinjectDependencyResolver(kernel));
    ...
}
```

After doing so the instance of `DependencyResolver.Current` changed to `NinjectDependencyResolver`.

Unfortunatelly this was not the end. I've got a `System.EntryPointNotFoundException` when trying to call `DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<PricingService>()`. But this was easily resolved with the help of [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13154241/entry-point-was-not-found-exception).

Comment: This no longer works. `new NinjectDependencyResolver(kernel)` now throws `ArgumentException`.