# IoC Unity Container injection in AuthorizeAttribute MVC 2

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, inversion-of-control, unity-container

Is there a way to inject the Unity container into an attribute in ASP.NET MVC 2?

Sounds quite a bit of work...

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7192543/injecting-dependencies-into-asp-net-mvc-3-action-filters-whats-wrong-with-this/7194467#7194467

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean attribute as action filters...
Have a look here, there's an exemple : https://web.archive.org/web/20140110094543/http://www.esenciadev.com/2010/05/dependency-injected-action-filters-in-asp-net-mvc2/

Comment: That URL now returns a 404 Page Not Found. Here is a snapshot of the page, courtesy of the Wayback Machine: https://web.archive.org/web/20140110094543/http://www.esenciadev.com/2010/05/dependency-injected-action-filters-in-asp-net-mvc2/