# Owin Web Api statup.cs with ninject

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, ninject

I have a problem to use web api Owin with ninject. When I try to use my web api , it was this error, and I can not fix this problem , I've tried many ways , none of which revolved my problem.

This error occurs when I boot my application

```
Error activating ModelValidatorProvider using binding from ModelValidatorProvider to 

NinjectDefaultModelValidatorProvider
A cyclical dependency was detected between the constructors of two services.

Activation path:
 3) Injection of dependency ModelValidatorProvider into parameter defaultModelValidatorProviders of constructor of type DefaultModelValidatorProviders
 2) Injection of dependency DefaultModelValidatorProviders into parameter defaultModelValidatorProviders of constructor of type NinjectDefaultModelValidatorProvider
 1) Request for ModelValidatorProvider

Suggestions:
 1) Ensure that you have not declared a dependency for ModelValidatorProvider on any implementations of the service.
 2) Consider combining the services into a single one to remove the cycle.
 3) Use property injection instead of constructor injection, and implement IInitializable
    if you need initialization logic to be run after property values have been injected
```

**My statup.cs**

```
var config = new HttpConfiguration();

OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions OAuthServerOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions()
{
    AllowInsecureHttp = true,
    TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/api/token"),
    AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(365),
    Provider = new SimpleAuthorizationServerProvider(),
};

// Token Generation
app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(OAuthServerOptions);
app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions());

WebApiConfig.Register(config);
app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);

config.DependencyResolver = new NinjectResolver(NinjectWebCommon.CreateKernel());


app.UseWebApi(config);
```

**My class DependencyResolver.cs**

```
public class NinjectDependencyScope : IDependencyScope, System.Web.Mvc.IDependencyResolver
{
    private IResolutionRoot resolver;

    internal NinjectDependencyScope(IResolutionRoot resolver)
    {
        Contract.Assert(resolver != null);

        this.resolver = resolver;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        resolver = null;
    }

    public object GetService(Type serviceType)
    {
        if (resolver == null)
            throw new ObjectDisposedException("this", "This scope has already been disposed");

        return resolver.TryGet(serviceType);
    }

    public IEnumerable<object> GetServices(Type serviceType)
    {
        if (resolver == null)
            throw new ObjectDisposedException("this", "This scope has already been disposed");

        return resolver.GetAll(serviceType);
    }
}

public class NinjectResolver : NinjectDependencyScope, System.Web.Mvc.IDependencyResolver, IDependencyResolver
{
    private IKernel kernel;

    public NinjectResolver(IKernel kernel)
        : base(kernel)
    {
        this.kernel = kernel;
    }

    public IDependencyScope BeginScope()
    {
        return new NinjectDependencyScope(kernel);
    }
}
```

**and my class NinjectWebCommon.cs**

```
 public static class NinjectWebCommon 
{
    private static readonly Bootstrapper bootstrapper = new Bootstrapper();

    /// <summary>
    /// Starts the application
    /// </summary>
    public static void Start() 
    {
        DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(typeof(OnePerRequestHttpModule));
        DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(typeof(NinjectHttpModule));
        bootstrapper.Initialize(CreateKernel);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Stops the application.
    /// </summary>
    public static void Stop()
    {
        bootstrapper.ShutDown();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates the kernel that will manage your application.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>The created kernel.</returns>
    public static IKernel CreateKernel()
    {
        var kernel = new StandardKernel();
        try
        {
            kernel.Bind<Func<IKernel>>().ToMethod(ctx => () => new Bootstrapper().Kernel);
            kernel.Bind<IHttpModule>().To<HttpApplicationInitializationHttpModule>();
            RegisterServices(kernel);

            return kernel;
        }
        catch
        {
            kernel.Dispose();
            throw;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Load your modules or register your services here!
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="kernel">The kernel.</param>
    private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
    {
        //Injeções de Depêndencias

        //Inject AppService
        kernel.Bind(typeof (IAppServiceBase<>)).To(typeof (AppServiceBase<>));
        kernel.Bind<ICanalDistribuicaoAppService>().To<CanalDistribuicaoAppService>();
        kernel.Bind<ICaracteristicasAppService>().To<CaracteristicasAppService>();
        kernel.Bind<ICaracteristicasValorAppService>().To<CaracteristicasValorAppService>();
        kernel.Bind<ICentroAppService>().To<CentroAppService>();
        kernel.Bind<IClassificacaoContabilAppService>().To<ClassificacaoContabilAppService>();
        kernel.Bind<IClienteAppService>().To<ClienteAppService>();
        kernel.Bind<IClienteModalidadeCentroAppService>().To<ClienteModalidadeCentroAppService>();
        kernel.Bind<IClienteTipoCarregamentoCentroAppService>().To<ClienteTipoCarregamentoCentroAppService>();
        kernel.Bind<IClienteEmailAppService>().To<ClienteEmailAppService>();
        kernel.Bind<IClienteGrupoAppService>().To<ClienteGrupoAppService>();
        kernel.Bind<IClienteStatusAppService>().To<ClienteStatusAppService>();
        kernel.Bind<ICondicaoPagamentoAppService>().To<CondicaoPagamentoAppService>();
        kernel.Bind<IDimensoesAppService>().To<DimensoesAppService>();
        kernel.Bind<IEmbalagemAppService>().To<EmbalagemAppService>();
        kernel.Bind<IEscritorioVendasAppService>().To<EscritorioVendasAppService>();
        kernel.Bind<IEstoqueAppService>().To<EstoqueAppService>();
        kernel.Bind<IGrupoProdutoRestritoAppService>().To<GrupoProdutoRestritoAppService>();
        kernel.Bind<ILiberacaoCIFAppService>().To<LiberacaoCIFAppService>();
        kernel.Bind<ILocalRetiradaAppService>().To<LocalRetiradaAppService>();
        kernel.Bind<IMateriaisAppService>().To<MateriaisAppService>();
        kernel.Bind<IModalidadeAppService>().To<ModalidadeAppService>();
        kernel.Bind<IOrganizacaoVendasAppService>().To<OrganizacaoVendasAppService>();
        kernel.Bind<IPedidoFavoritoAppService>().To<PedidoFavoritoAppService>();
        kernel.Bind<IProdutoAppService>().To<ProdutoAppService>();
        kernel.Bind<IRamoEmpresaAppService>().To<RamoEmpresaAppService>();
        kernel.Bind<ISegmentoMercadoAppService>().To<SegmentoMercadoAppService>();
        kernel.Bind<ISetorAtividadeAppService>().To<SetorAtividadeAppService>();
        kernel.Bind<IStatusReservaAppService>().To<StatusReservaAppService>();
        kernel.Bind<ISubstituicaoFiscalAppService>().To<SubstituicaoFiscalAppService>();
        kernel.Bind<ITipoCarregamentoAppService>().To<TipoCarregamentoAppService>();
        kernel.Bind<ITipoEmailAppService>().To<TipoEmailAppService>();
        kernel.Bind<IUtilizacaoAppService>().To<UtilizacaoAppService>();
        kernel.Bind<IUsuarioAppService>().To<UsuarioAppService>();

        //Inject Services
        kernel.Bind(typeof (IServiceBase<>)).To(typeof (ServiceBase<>));
        kernel.Bind<ICanalDistribuicaoService>().To<CanalDistribuicaoService>();
        kernel.Bind<ICaracteristicasService>().To<CaracteristicasService>();
        kernel.Bind<ICaracteristicasValorService>().To<CaracteristicasValorService>();
        kernel.Bind<ICentroService>().To<CentroService>();
        kernel.Bind<IClassificacaoContabilService>().To<ClassificacaoContabilService>();
        kernel.Bind<IClienteService>().To<ClienteService>();
        kernel.Bind<IClienteModalidadeCentroService>().To<ClienteModalidadeCentroService>();
        kernel.Bind<IClienteTipoCarregamentoCentroService>().To<ClienteTipoCarregamentoCentroService>();
        kernel.Bind<IClienteEmailService>().To<ClienteEmailService>();
        kernel.Bind<IClienteGrupoService>().To<ClienteGrupoService>();
        kernel.Bind<IClienteStatusService>().To<ClienteStatusService>();
        kernel.Bind<ICondicaoPagamentoService>().To<CondicaoPagamentoService>();
        kernel.Bind<IDimensoesService>().To<DimensoesService>();
        kernel.Bind<IEmbalagemService>().To<EmbalagemService>();
        kernel.Bind<IEscritorioVendasService>().To<EscritorioVendasService>();
        kernel.Bind<IEstoqueService>().To<EstoqueService>();
        kernel.Bind<IGrupoProdutoRestritoService>().To<GrupoProdutoRestritoService>();
        kernel.Bind<ILiberacaoCIFService>().To<LiberacaoCIFService>();
        kernel.Bind<ILocalRetiradaService>().To<LocalRetiradaService>();
        kernel.Bind<IMateriaisService>().To<MateriaisService>();
        kernel.Bind<IModalidadeService>().To<ModalidadeService>();
        kernel.Bind<IOrganizacaoVendasService>().To<OrganizacaoVendasService>();
        kernel.Bind<IPedidoFavoritoService>().To<PedidoFavoritoService>();
        kernel.Bind<IProdutoService>().To<ProdutoService>();
        kernel.Bind<IRamoEmpresaService>().To<RamoEmpresaService>();
        kernel.Bind<ISegmentoMercadoService>().To<SegmentoMercadoService>();
        kernel.Bind<ISetorAtividadeService>().To<SetorAtividadeService>();
        kernel.Bind<IStatusReservaService>().To<StatusReservaService>();
        kernel.Bind<ISubstituicaoFiscalService>().To<SubstituicaoFiscalService>();
        kernel.Bind<ITipoCarregamentoService>().To<TipoCarregamentoService>();
        kernel.Bind<ITipoEmailService>().To<TipoEmailService>();
        kernel.Bind<IUtilizacaoService>().To<UtilizacaoService>();
        kernel.Bind<IUsuarioService>().To<UsuarioService>();

        //Inject Repositories
        kernel.Bind(typeof (IRepositoryBase<>)).To(typeof (RepositoryBase<>));
        kernel.Bind<ICanalDistribuicaoRepository>().To<CanalDistribuicaoRepository>();
        kernel.Bind<ICaracteristicasRepository>().To<CaracteristicasRepository>();
        kernel.Bind<ICaracteristicasValorRepository>().To<CaracteristicasValorRepository>();
        kernel.Bind<ICentroRepository>().To<CentroRepository>();
        kernel.Bind<IClassificacaoContabilRepository>().To<ClassificacaoContabilRepository>();
        kernel.Bind<IClienteRepository>().To<ClienteRepository>();
        kernel.Bind<IClienteModalidadeCentroRepository>().To<ClienteModalidadeCentroRepository>();
        kernel.Bind<IClienteTipoCarregamentoCentroRepository>().To<ClienteTipoCarregamentoCentroRepository>();
        kernel.Bind<IClienteEmailRepository>().To<ClienteEmailRepository>();
        kernel.Bind<IClienteGrupoRepository>().To<ClienteGrupoRepository>();
        kernel.Bind<IClienteStatusRepository>().To<ClienteStatusRepository>();
        kernel.Bind<ICondicaoPagamentoRepository>().To<CondicaoPagamentoRepository>();
        kernel.Bind<IDimensoesRepository>().To<DimensoesRepository>();
        kernel.Bind<IEmbalagemRepository>().To<EmbalagemRepository>();
        kernel.Bind<IEscritorioVendasRepository>().To<EscritorioVendasRepository>();
        kernel.Bind<IEstoqueRepository>().To<EstoqueRepository>();
        kernel.Bind<IGrupoProdutoRestritoRepository>().To<GrupoProdutoRestritoRepository>();
        kernel.Bind<ILiberacaoCIFRepository>().To<LiberacaoCIFRepository>();
        kernel.Bind<ILocalRetiradaRepository>().To<LocalRetiradaRepository>();
        kernel.Bind<IMateriaisRepository>().To<MateriaisRepository>();
        kernel.Bind<IModalidadeRepository>().To<ModalidadeRepository>();
        kernel.Bind<IOrganizacaoVendasRepository>().To<OrganizacaoVendasRepository>();
        kernel.Bind<IPedidoFavoritoRepository>().To<PedidoFavoritoRepository>();
        kernel.Bind<IProdutoRepository>().To<ProdutoRepository>();
        kernel.Bind<IRamoEmpresaRepository>().To<RamoEmpresaRepository>();
        kernel.Bind<ISegmentoMercadoRepository>().To<SegmentoMercadoRepository>();
        kernel.Bind<ISetorAtividadeRepository>().To<SetorAtividadeRepository>();
        kernel.Bind<IStatusReservaRepository>().To<StatusReservaRepository>();
        kernel.Bind<ISubstituicaoFiscalRepository>().To<SubstituicaoFiscalRepository>();
        kernel.Bind<ITipoCarregamentoRepository>().To<TipoCarregamentoRepository>();
        kernel.Bind<ITipoEmailRepository>().To<TipoEmailRepository>();
        kernel.Bind<IUtilizacaoRepository>().To<UtilizacaoRepository>();
        kernel.Bind<IUsuarioRepository>().To<UsuarioRepository>();

    }        
}
```

Help me plis.

Comment: Similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26312231/ninjectdependencyresolver-fails-binding-modelvalidatorprovider), no answer yet.

Comment: What version are you using? Could you ensure that you have latest version? [Cyclic Dependancy Exception](https://github.com/ninject/ninject/issues/131)

Answer (score 0):

I know its very old Q but still comes up in google in top 3 search for this error. So as a solution just remove ninject.web.webapi and its dependencies like ninject.web.webapi.webhost.