# Using Ninject in two projects in one solution, a cyclical dependency exception

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, ninject

I'm using Ninject in two projects in the same solution. In MVC with Views and Web.API projects. But I'm having the following exception from Web API `NinjectWebCommon.cs` when trying to run both project at one time -

> Error activating ModelValidatorProvider using binding from
>   ModelValidatorProvider to NinjectDefaultModelValidatorProvider A
>   cyclical dependency was detected between the constructors of two
>   services.

But if I run only Web API project, I don't encounter the above mentioned exception.
I have `NinjectWebCommon.cs` file in both projects.

In Web API -

```
public static void Start() //The method looks the same for MVC Project
{
    DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(typeof(OnePerRequestHttpModule));
    DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(typeof(NinjectHttpModule));
    bootstrapper.Initialize(CreateKernel); 
}

private static IKernel CreateKernel()
{
    var kernel = new StandardKernel();
    try
    {
        kernel.Bind<Func<IKernel>>().ToMethod(ctx => () => new Bootstrapper().Kernel);
        kernel.Bind<IHttpModule>().To<HttpApplicationInitializationHttpModule>();           

        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new NinjectResolver(kernel);    
        RegisterServices(kernel);
        return kernel;
     }
     catch
     {
        kernel.Dispose();
        throw;
     }
}        
private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
{
    WebIoC.RegisterServices(kernel);
}
```

And MVC project -

```
private static IKernel CreateKernel()
{
    var kernel = new StandardKernel();
       try
       {
           kernel.Bind<Func<IKernel>>().ToMethod(ctx => () => new Bootstrapper().Kernel);
           kernel.Bind<IHttpModule>().To<HttpApplicationInitializationHttpModule>();               

           RegisterServices(kernel);
           RegisterServiceLocator(kernel);

           return kernel;
        }
        catch
        {
            kernel.Dispose();
            throw;
        }
}

private static void RegisterServiceLocator(StandardKernel kernel)
{
    var locator = new NinjectServiceLocator(kernel);

    ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => locator);
}

private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
{
    kernel.Bind<IFormsAuthenticationService>().To<FormsAuthenticationService>();
    kernel.Bind<IAdMembershService>().To<ActiveDirectoryMembershipService>();
    kernel.Bind<IFacebookAuthenticationService>().To<FacebookAuthenticationService>();            
}
```

I'm encountering this exception in `bootstrapper.Initialize(CreateKernel);` in `Start()` method. Has anyone encountered the same issue?

**Update:** I'm also using the following code for startup in both projects, if it matters.

```
[assembly: WebActivatorEx.PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(Path.to.NinjectWebCommon), "Start")]
[assembly: WebActivatorEx.ApplicationShutdownMethodAttribute(typeof(Path.to.NinjectWebCommon), "Stop")]
```

Comment: Try removing this line in your web api and let me know the outcome: GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new NinjectResolver(kernel);

Comment: In this case I'm getting - An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Core.dll but was not handled in user code
Additional information: Sequence contains no elements

But from MVC Project NinjectWebCommon.cs now.

Comment: Are you using the same version of Ninject on both projects (this could be the problem if you are not)? What version are you using? Has this occured after an update? Are the updates done via nuget?

Comment: I'm using Ninject 3.2.0.0 for both projects. This exception started appearing when I moved Web API Controllers to a separate Web API project. At first I had both MVC and WebAPI in one project with the one NinjectWebCommon.cs only. I've downloaded the packages via nuget. I think it's also worth mentioning that if I completely exclude NinjectWebCommon.cs from Web API project, MVC project runs fine, without exceptions.

Comment: What does WebIoC.RegisterServices(kernel); do?

Comment: Simply a static method with bindings.

Comment: By any chance binding the same interfaces to different models?

Comment: No, all interfaces are different...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NinjectDependencyResolver fails binding ModelValidatorProvider](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26312231/ninjectdependencyresolver-fails-binding-modelvalidatorprovider)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has happened to others before, see [Ninject Issue 131](https://github.com/ninject/ninject/issues/131).

[Arindamat](https://github.com/arindamdat) came up with the following fix:

```
_kernel
    .Bind<DefaultModelValidatorProviders>()
    .ToConstant(new DefaultModelValidatorProviders(
         config.Services.GetServices(
             typeof (ModelValidatorProvider))
         .Cast<ModelValidatorProvider>()));
```

which gets rid of the cyclic dependency.

However, the **root cause** is usually a botched up installation of ninject. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27399451/684096) answer shows how to fix it.