# AutoFac Injection into attribute

Tags: dependency-injection, autofac

So I have a need for injecting a number of different services into an authorization attribute I'm using. For simplicity I will leave this to show the configuration manager.

```
public class FeatureAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public IConfigurationManager ConfigurationManager;

    private readonly string _feature;
    public FeatureAuthorizeAttribute(string feature)
    {
        _feature = feature;

        var test  = ConfigurationManager.GetCdnPath();
    }
}
```

Which would be used as follows

```
[FeatureAuthorize("Admin")]
```

I have tried to use constructor injection

```
public FeatureAuthorizeAttribute(string feature, IConfigurationManager configurationManager)
{
   ConfigurationManager = configurationManager;
   _feature = feature
}
```

However this just causes an error when I attempt

```
[FeatureAuthorize("Admin", IConfigurationManager)]
```

Which seems like the wrong way to go about it in the first place.  I'm assuming that I need to register my custom authorization attribute with the container to get it to start picking up

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Instead of trying to use Dependency Injection with attributes (which you can't do in any sane, useful way), create [Passive Attributes](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/13/passive-attributes).

Specifically, in this case, assuming that this is an ASP.NET MVC scenario, you can't derive from [AuthorizeAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute). Instead, you should make your Authorization service look for your custom attribute, and implement [IAuthorizationFilter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.iauthorizationfilter.aspx). Then add the filter to your application's configuration.

More details can be found in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7194467/126014.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you! Mark you are a gentleman and a scholar.  The only piece I'm a little fuzzy on is how I get this custom filter to correlate to my custom attribute

Comment: @JonGear If you look at the example given in the [Passive Attributes](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/13/passive-attributes) article, you'll notice that it starts by looking after the custom attribute in `actionContext.ActionDescriptor`. In MVC, IIRC you can do the same with [ActionExecutingContext](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.actionexecutingcontext).