# Custom authentication and authorization in ASP.NET MVC5?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication, asp.net-mvc-5, authorization

I have the following database structure
[image: DB structure, authentication/authorization part]
and I have to build authentication/authorization for an ASP.NET MVC 5 site.

The DB schema works as follows: every `user` belongs to a `group`, and each `group` can be granted/denied a `permission`. Each permission matches an action on a controller (let's say, a `Petitions` controller would have the following actions: `List`, `View`, `Add`, `Edit`, `Delete`, `VoteFor`, `VoteAgainst`, `Reject` and `Approve`, and each action is an entry in the `Permissions` table).

The purpose of all this is that, each time a user invokes an action, the site verifies that the user belongs to a group that has been granted permission over that action, and reacts accordingly.

An example: let's say the admin grants the `PetitionsList`, `PetitionsView`, `PetitionsApprove` and `PetitionsReject` permissions to the `Managers` group, and the `PetitionsList`, `PetitionsView`, `PetitionsAdd`, `PetitionsVoteFor` and `PetitionsVoteAgainst` to the `Users` group.

In this case, both groups can

- list petitions
- view a petition

Managers can

- approve a petition
- reject a petition

but they can't

- vote for a petition
- vote against a petition.

In the same way, users can

- add a petition
- vote for a petition
- vote against a petition

but they can't:

- approve a petition
- reject a petition

and neither can edit or delete a petition.

I'd really like to leverage the attributes functionality in MVC 5. My idea is to build custom attributes that do all the authentication/authorization behind scenes. Something like this:

```
public class PetitionsController : Controller
{
    [MyCustomAuth(Permission="PetitionsList",Groups="Users,Managers")]
    public ActionResult List()
    {
        //show the list of petitions
    }

    [MyCustomAuth(Permission="PetitionsView",Groups="Users,Managers")]
    public ActionResult View()
    {
        //show a specific petition
    }

    [MyCustomAuth(Permission="PetitionsAdd",Groups="Users")]
    public ActionResult Add()
    {
        //show add petition form
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [MyCustomAuth(Permission="PetitionsAdd",Groups="Users")]
    public ActionResult Add(object[] params)
    {
        //save new petition
    }

    [MyCustomAuth(Permission="PetitionsEdit",Groups="Admins")]
    public ActionResult Edit(int id)
    {
        //show edit petition form
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [MyCustomAuth(Permission="PetitionsEdit",Groups="Admins")]
    public ActionResult Edit(object[] params)
    {
        //save changes to petition
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [MyCustomAuth(Permission="PetitionsDelete",Groups="Admins")]
    public ActionResult Delete(int_id)
    {
        //delete petition
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [MyCustomAuth(Permission="PetitionsVoteFor",Groups="Users")]
    public ActionResult VoteFor(int id)
    {
        //add vote supporting petition
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [MyCustomAuth(Permission="PetitionsVoteAgainst",Groups="Users")]
    public ActionResult VoteAgainst(int id)
    {
        //add vote against petition
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [MyCustomAuth(Permission="PetitionsApprove",Groups="Managers")]
    public ActionResult Approve(int id)
    {
        //approve petition
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [MyCustomAuth(Permission="PetitionsReject",Groups="Managers")]
    public ActionResult Reject(int id)
    {
        //reject petition
    }
}
```

Please note the `MyCustomAuth` attribute over every action. I want that attribute to do the heavy lifting of saying if the user is actually authorized to do that action, behind the scenes. Of course, in case it's not authenticated/authorized, the attribute should redirect to login page/401/somewhere else.

My question is, where do I start? Am I expected to implement some special interface/inherit from some class in MVC 5? Or do I have to write this from scratch?

Also, thanks in advance for reading this wall of text and for giving me any tips/pointers in the right direction.

Comment: Generally, database access code should not be in attributes (can't unit test the code), so a better solution would be to have a service that return a value indicating if the user has the correct permission of not. The code in each controller method might be something like `if (!_permissionService.HasPermission(DocumentType.Petitions, ActionType.Edit, user.ID) { // denied }`

Comment: How about creating a service that verifies the user has access to the specified action and calling the service from the attribute class? Makes testing the verification easier and I still get to write only an attribute over the action (the best of both worlds?).

Comment: Just ensure that you can use DI so that you controllers can be united tested. Suggest you look at the 2 top answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7192543/injecting-dependencies-into-asp-net-mvc-3-action-filters-whats-wrong-with-this)

Answer (score 1):

I think you can start with below Custom Authorization Filter. It also handle cases for both - ajax request and full page request.

```
 public class MyCustomAuthAttribute : FilterAttribute, IAuthorizationFilter
    {
        public string Permission { get; set; }
        public string Groups { get; set; }

        public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
        {
            bool isauthorized = CheckIfUserIsAuthorized();
            if (!isauthorized)
                context.Result = new HttpUnauthorizedResult(); // mark unauthorized

            // Only do something if we are about to give a HttpUnauthorizedResult and we are in AJAX mode.
            if (filterContext.Result is HttpUnauthorizedResult && filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
            {
                filterContext.Result = new JsonResult
                {
                    Data = new { Success = false, Message = "Unauthorized Access" },
                    JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
                };
            }
            else
            {
                base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);
                if (filterContext.Result is HttpUnauthorizedResult)
                {
                    HttpContext.Current.Session.Abandon();
                    System.Web.Security.FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
                    filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("Your Login Page.");
                }
            }
        }

        private bool IsAuthorizedUser()
        {
            // use Permission, Groups and your logic
        }
    }
```

and use it the same way you mentioned:

```
 [MyCustomAuth(Permission="PetitionsEdit",Groups="Admins")]
```