# MVC3 with IoC: too many parameters in a base controller. Any alternative?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, controller, inversion-of-control, controller-factory

I am using MVC 3. Suppose I have a Base Controller and several derived controllers.
I am using IoC and my base controller constructor looks like this:

```
private readonly ICacheProvider _cacheProvider;
private readonly ILoggerProvider _loggerProvider
private readonly IAuditProvider _auditProvider
public abstract class MyControllerBase : Controller
{
  protected MyControllerBase(ICacheProvider cacheProvider, ILoggerProvider loggerProvider, IAuditProvider auditProvider, ...)
  {
    _cacheProvider = cacheProvider;
    _loggerProvider = loggerProvider;
    _auditProvider = auditProvider;
    ...
  }
}
```

So far so good? Maybe.
However, each of my derived controllers needs to define a constructor that matches the base class constructor signature, for example:

```
public class MyDerivedController1 : MyControllerBase
{
        public MyDerivedController1(ICacheProvider cacheProvider, ILoggerProvider loggerProvider, IAuditProvider auditProvider, ...)
        : base(cacheProvider, loggerProvider, auditProvider, ...)
    { }
}
```

And that is my problem, because I have to maintain the "verbose" constructor in all my derived controllers.
If I need to add a new provider I have to refactor all my derived controllers.

I thought I would create a ServiceProvider (or Service **Locator** ?) class (and IServiceProvider interface), which would have a constructor and all providers as parameters (where IoC would do its job) and expose them as properties.
Then my base constructor and derived constructors would only have the IServiceProvider as a parameter.

However I am concerned that this approach will have some negative impacts, for example:
1- Hidden implementation: I don't know which provider I use or need unless I check the implementation.
2- Hard to test: when the constructor contains parameters I can easily test it and I know what to expect (auto-documented).

Does anyone have any suggestion or comments?

Comment: What exactly is `MyControllerBase` doing? Would the decorator pattern be an alternative?

Comment: @Daniel, MyControllerBase contains several helper methods (somehow extending the base Controller class of MVC), contains the custom Authorize attribute and other attributes, and other methods used to get logged in User data, check if Terms&Conditions page should be displayed, etc.

Comment: This blog post has helped me a little bit, but it is only applied when you can extract a common behavior or group more than 1 provider together. What if in my case I have 5 or more providers that I need in my Controller with completely different responsibilities? http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/02/RefactoringtoAggregateServices/

Comment: You can use property injection instead of constructor injection. Common practice however is to only use property injection for optional dependencies.

Comment: @LostInComputer that's an option to consider. However in my scenario I believe I don't have any optional dependency, they are all mandatory for most of the controllers. I  thought this was a very common problem, so I guess there is something really wrong with my design, but at the moment I don't have a better idea on how to improve it.

Comment: @AndreCruz: The point that your base controller has so many dependencies hints at a possible violation of the Single Responsibility Principle: Your base controller might be doing too much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research I was unable to find a good solution. As mentioned by Daniel Hilgarth the controller has too many dependencies which violates SRP. I agree.
Given that this is an existing application I cannot refactor and re-design the whole thing.
For example, I would like to move dependencies such as ICacheProvider, ILoggerProvider and IAuditProvider to another layer, which would be responsible for retrieving the data from the repository.

I don't want to start a new discussion here, but I don't like the idea of referencing Entity Framework in my MVC web project. I would prefer to create a Data Access layer and remove completely the references to EF.
So, back to my problem, I have a Base Controller with X dependencies and all derived controllers need a constructor with all those references (as explained in my question above).

I've considered a few options:

1) Using a Service Locator. After reading quite a few posts, I've decided to ignore this option.

[Is it bad to use servicelocation instead of constructor injection to avoid writing loads of factory classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1599811/is-it-bad-to-use-servicelocation-instead-of-constructor-injection-to-avoid-writi)

[IoC.Resolve vs Constructor Injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176833/ioc-resolve-vs-constructor-injection)

http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern/

2) Using Aggregate Services. This is a good idea, but I couldn't group my dependencies and I decided to ignore this one too.

[How to avoid Dependency Injection constructor madness?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2420193/how-to-avoid-dependency-injection-constructor-madness)

http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/02/RefactoringtoAggregateServices/

3) Creating a new Provider which exposes all the other dependencies as properties.
I am not completely satisfied with this option because it somehow hides the implementation details. But after all considerations I have decided to implement it.
Find below the new interface and class created:

```
    public interface IMyControllerProvider
    {
    ICacheProvider CacheProvider { get; }

    ILoggerProvider LoggerProvider { get; }

    IAuditProvider AuditProvider { get; }

     ...
    }


    public class MyControllerProvider : IMyControllerProvider
    {
    private readonly ICacheProvider _cacheProvider;
    private readonly ILoggerProvider _loggerProvider;
    private readonly IAuditProvider _auditProvider;
    .....

    public MyControllerProvider(ICacheProvider cacheProvider, ILoggerProvider loggerProvider, IAuditProvider auditProvider, ...)
    {
       _cacheProvider = cacheProvider;
       _loggerProvider = loggerProvider;
       _auditProvider = auditProvider;
       ...
    }

    public ICacheProvider CacheProvider { get { return _context; } }
    public ILoggerProvider LoggerProvider { get { return _context; } }
    public IAuditProvider AuditProvider { get { return _context; } }
}
```

After that I refactored my base controller and all derived controllers to use IMyControllerProvider instead.
It works fine because:

1- The derived controllers have now a constructor with a single dependency.

2- Although the new dependency **IMyControllerProvider** "hides" the real dependencies, when testing the controller it is still easy to understand that there are other dependencies (the constructor documents that).

```
    private readonly ICacheProvider _cacheProvider;
private readonly ILoggerProvider _loggerProvider
private readonly IAuditProvider _auditProvider
public abstract class MyControllerBase : Controller
{
    protected MyControllerBase(IMyControllerProvider myControllerProvider)
    {
        _cacheProvider = myControllerProvider.CacheProvider;
        _loggerProvider = myControllerProvider.LoggerProvider;
        _auditProvider = myControllerProvider.AuditProvider;
    }
}

public class MyDerivedController1 : MyControllerBase
{
        public MyDerivedController1(IMyControllerProvider myControllerProvider)
          : base(myControllerProvider)
    { }
}
```

Not the best solution, but the only one I could come up with given the restriction of refactoring the whole application.